# "from . import app" in this statement what is meaning of '.'

Tags: python, import

I am new to python. I found this line "from . import app" on the net. When i search more about it on net i didn't find any clue. so, if someone can help me to know significance of char '.' in above line.

Comment: It means, "from the same directory where I am, import the app module"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but some people use .import to import there own file from the same folder like

```
.import (file name)
```

but for my system I have to not do this , u can see by removing "." if it matters or not.